# Does Twig allow use of associative arrays as a flash session variables?

Tags: symfony, twig, silex

I'm using Silex, and I'm wondering if it is possible to use an associative array for a flash session variable? I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's what I've been trying:

**Setting up the flash var in my app file.**

```
$my_array = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'veggie' => 'carrot');
$app['session']->setFlash('myFlashVar', $my_array);
```

**And used in Twig like this.**

```
{% set myVar = app.session.getFlash('myFlashVar') %}
// And so that we don't get an error, check to see if the key exists
{% if 'fruit' in myVar|keys  %}{{ myVar['fruit'] }}{% endif %}
```

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setFlash` and `getFlash` a deprecated methods and therefore should be avoided.

You can get your code to run by using the favored methods provided by Session::getFlashBag (pun intended?)

PHP:

```
$my_array = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'veggie' => 'carrot');
$app['session']->getFlashBag()->set('myFlashVar', $my_array);
```

TWIG:

```
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('myFlashVar') %}

    {{ flashMessage }}

{% endfor %}
```

Disclaimer: I only tested this using the Symfony2 (2.16) framework - not Silex. In Symfony2 it is:

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('myFlashVar', $my_array);
```

Comment: do NOT recommend a method that is deprecated. It is only there for backwards comp. Use `Session::getFlashBag()`, which returns a `FlashBagInterface` instance (where you can use the `set` method to add items).

Comment: @WouterJ I quote myself: "From cross-reading the code it would be advisable to not using setFlash(...) and setFlashes(...)"

Comment: why don't you change your example to something that works and is correct?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and suggestions, guys. Can you write (or modify) a complete answer with a code example (using the current recommended method). This would help both me and others.

Comment: @madflow: Thanks! I'll test with Silex tomorrow and report back here with the results. Thanks again! (I'll mark accepted after I test).